# Utilising the Android Camera Flash + Timing

Tags: java, android, camera, click

I'm kinda new to the dev scene, I'm in the middle of an Android project.
I am trying to utilise the mobile phone camera flash. I'm trying to make it flash on and off in a repetitive motion. Below is a clip from my .java file.

```
    public void clickGo(View view) {

    Bundle newtempo = getIntent().getExtras();
    int tempo = newtempo.getInt("tempoData");
    int scaledTempo = 60000/tempo;


    while (true) {
        long futureTime1a = System.currentTimeMillis() + (100);
        long futureTime1b = System.currentTimeMillis() + (scaledTempo - 100);


        while (System.currentTimeMillis() < futureTime1a) {
            setFlashlightOn();
        }
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() < futureTime1b) {
            setFlashlightOff();
        }
    }
```

Let me explain what's going on...
So I've gained data from another activity then scaled it to a milleseconds value. 
I've put the rest of the algorithm in a while(true) loop, just until I can get it working properly. I set two times, one with 100 milliseconds, and one with the scaled millesecond value MINUS the 100 milliseconds.
I then apply these two timings to turn the flash on then off.

In theory, this should work. I have data inputted from another activity which scales the number into milliseconds as shown. The concept does work, as lower numbers and higher numbers make the flash beat slower and quicker on my phone. However, the precision is my issue. When I play a click beat to the same time of the app, it's easy to tell that some flashes come in slower, or last longer.etc. I was wondering what this could possibly be? I've stripped down most of the code to a completely bare script (as I thought it could be a processing issue). It could also be the way I've implemented the time feature - if anyone else has a more efficient way, I would love to hear it!

As I said at the beginning, I'm relatively new to the dev scene, so I would appreciate it if you could answer with this in mind :)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The internal clock for computers is somewhat unreliable in quick successions like what you want.  I would recommend using a [timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) to achieve what you want.

Comment: I'm afraid this didn't work, I'm having the same problem - the flash isn't flashing on and off in a precise motion, still sometimes the flash hangs on too long, or didn't turn on quick enough. I used the `timer.scheduleAtFixedRate()` from the `Timer` class.